# When did these characters die in the Battle for Hogwarts?

Tags: harry-potter

Maybe I missed the bit where there deaths were mentioned but I could have sworn they were fine one minute and dead the next.

When were

> Tonks and Lupin

killed in the Battle for Hogwarts?

Comment: It is quite common in a battle that people were fine one minute and dead the next.

Comment: @RalfFriedl That reminds me of Jack Kirby's account about World War II. One second, he was talking with a lieutenant, and the next instant the lieutenant was a red smear on the wall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We don't see their deaths *on camera* (as it were). We're following Harry at that point, seeing him trying to get the diadem from the Room of Requirement.

**Alive.**

> ‘Have you seen Remus?’ Tonks called after him.
> ‘He was duelling Dolohov,’ shouted Aberforth, ‘haven’t seen him since!’
> ‘Tonks,’ said Ginny, ‘Tonks, I’m sure he’s OK –’
> But Tonks had run off into the dust after Aberforth.
> Ginny turned, helpless, to Harry, Ron and Hermione.

**About an hour later. Dead.**

> Without a word to Harry, Ron and Hermione walked away. Harry saw
> Hermione approach Ginny, whose face was swollen and blotchy, and hug
> her. Ron joined Bill, Fleur and Percy, who flung an arm around Ron’s
> shoulders. As Ginny and Hermione moved closer to the rest of the
> family, Harry had a clear view of the bodies lying next to Fred: Remus
> and Tonks, pale and still and peaceful-looking, apparently asleep
> beneath the dark, enchanted ceiling.

---

JKR confirmed in [an interview](https://archive.org/stream/J.k.RowlingChatTranscript/ChatJkRowling_djvu.txt) that Remus was killed by Dolohov (presumably in the duel mentioned above) and that Tonks was killed by Bellatrix.

> **Q.** *Who killed Remus and Tonks? I think if I knew this, I would get some closure over the very sad, but understandable, death of two of my favorite characters*
>
> **J.K. Rowling:** *I'm so sorry! I met a couple on launch night who had come dressed as Lupin and Tonks, and I felt dreadfully guilty as I signed their books. **Remus was killed by Dolohov and Tonks by Bellatrix.***